# How to calculate percentage in column?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've got a task to calculate smallest salary in the departments and how many percents is it from total salary.
Also i can use only one select statement and **probably** I need to use window functions.

This is how i started:

```
     SELECT distinct department_id,
     min(salary) over(partition by department_id) as min_sal
     FROM employees;
```

But if I use RATIO_TO_REPORT function it show all table, not grouped by department_id.

Comment: do you need one row per employee in the output (very odd), or just one row per DEPARTMENT? Or do you need to get the employee name with the lowest salary, too?

Comment: Share some sample data set and the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like

```
select min(salary) as min_salary, round( min(salary)/sum(salary) * 100 , 1 ) as percent
from   employees
group by department_id
;
```

If you also need the employee's name who has the least salary in each department (assuming there's always only one), then add

```
    , min(empl_name) keep (dense_rank first order by salary) as min_sal_empl_name
```

to the `SELECT` statement. If there can be ties for the least salary, and you need all the employees, please say so - in that case you probably need analytic functions as you guessed. Something like:

```
select empl_name, salary, round(salary/tot_sal*100, 1) as percent
from   ( select empl_name, salary, 
                sum(salary) over (partition by department_id)            as tot_sal,
                rank() over (partition by department_id order by salary) as rn
         from   employees 
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

**Added**: OP indicated they need salary as percentage of total salary (across all departments) after all. This can be done by combining `ratio_to_report()` with empty windowing condition (no "partition by" anything) with `rank()` partitioned by department to pick up least salary in each department.

If you don't like `over ()` for the windowing clause in `ratio_to_report()`, it can also be written as `over (partition by null)` to make it super-clear no partitioning is intended or needed.

The solution uses the EMP table in the SCOTT schema for testing, since the original post did not include sample data.

```
select deptno, empno, ename, sal, percent
from   (
         select empno, ename, sal, deptno,
                round(100 * ratio_to_report(sal) over (), 1)   as percent,
                rank() over (partition by deptno order by sal) as rn
         from   scott.emp
       )
where  rn = 1
;


DEPTNO  EMPNO  ENAME    SAL  PERCENT
------  -----  ------  ----  -------
10       7934  MILLER  1300      4.5
20       7369  SMITH    800      2.8
30       7900  JAMES    950      3.3
```

Comment: yes, I need all of them and I used query similar to your last one, but there's the catch, it can one select statement. And your first query is perfect in every way, except it calculates how percents in a wrong way.

Comment: @E.Saraf -  A select statement with a subquery (a sub-select statement) is still a single select statement. Then: if you think my first calculation is wrong, please explain in what way it is wrong - otherwise I can't take you seriously. (You are probably wrong anyway, but I can't tell you how if you don't share what you believe is incorrect.)

Comment: Your calculations is right. But I need to know how many percents department minimal salary is from total sum, not department sum. In second query it's easy to fix, but is there a way to do it in your first query?

Comment: @E.Saraf - YOU wrote this, not me:  *But if I use RATIO_TO_REPORT function it show all table, not grouped by department_id.* What did you mean by it? If you need percentage compared to total sum, NOT by department, then what did you mean by that last sentence in your post? To me it meant you need the result grouped by department id, and RATIO_TO_REPORT couldn't be used because it didn't group that way. (By the way, RATIO_TO_REPORT **can** be used both ways, but that's another matter.)

Comment: @E.Saraf - posting a solution to compute percentage from total salary for company, and using ratio_to_report to show how it can be used.